# String conver to float error python with nput file

Tags: python

Hi i have a question regarding the understand code:

```
grades = [float(a) for a in list[1].split(' ')]
```

I get the next error:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '6.7\nFrans'

'6.7\nFrans' is from the input file .txt

Comment: its pretty obvious that `6.7\nFrans` is not a float, 6.7 is only, try splitting by `\n`.

Comment: I have added the '\n' to it and i am getting now the next error:
could not convert string to float: '4.3 4.9 6.7'

Comment: post sample from your file, cant say what's wrong without knowing the input

Comment: Just split it another time by spaces

Comment: Just do `.split()`. `.split(' ')` only splits on spaces, `.split('\n')` only splits on newlines. If you don't give it an argument, it will just split on all blocks of whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Split using both metrics with the built in library `re`:

```
import re

grades = [float(a) for a in re.split(' |\n',list[1])]
```